# System.Web.Helpers.WebMail.Send() Gives "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, multithreading, webmail

I have this thread:

```
public static Thread BGtimer = new Thread(() =>
        {
            TimeoOutAction action = new TimeoOutAction();
            string CurrentTime = "";
            while (true)
            {
                CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                if (CurrentTime == "10:10:00") {
                    action.SendTimeOutResult("");  
                }                
            }
        });
```

```
public class TimeoOutAction
    {

        
        public void SendTimeOutResult(string type)
        {
            WebMail.Send("email", "", "", null, null, null, false, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        }
    }
```

When I run this code it give this error at WebMail.Send()

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The same WebMail.Send() method works when its not being called from a thread on other parts but here it gives the error, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, I understand what a nullReferenceException is, I'm not sure why its throwing that error in this specific setup

Comment: Short answer: because something is `null`. Perhaps you could provide the full stack trace in addition to just the error message?